# Spring + Jersey + Filter + @Provider

Tags: java, spring, rest, filter, jersey

I tried to configure Jersey with Spring using just annotations. I annotated my resource classes with `@Path` and `@Component` annotations. Everything worked fine until I tried to configure some filters. I created filter like this:

```
@Service
@Provider @PreMatching
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public MyFilter() {
        System.out.println("MyFilter()");
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("filtered");
        return request;
    }
}
```

It looks like bean is created and filter is registered in Jersey as when calling the resource I see:

```
INFO: Registering Spring bean, myFilter, of type pl.igt.filter.MyFilter as provider class
```

next to info about registration of resource components. 
I can call my resources and it works fine, but filter is never used actually.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>IGT</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <!-- jersey 1.x -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- 
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>pl.igt.filter.MyFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
         -->
    </servlet>

    <!-- jersey 2.x 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>pl.igt.rest.JerseyApplication</param-value>            
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  
    -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.igt.rest" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.igt.filter" />
</beans>
```

Comment: What if you try register this filter in your pl.igt.rest.JerseyApplication?

Comment: I don't get why you are using two different Jersey versions?? That filter wouldn't even work with Jersey 2, as it's a Jersey 1 filter. See [Spring support for Jersey 2](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html)

Comment: Also see [Filters for Jersey 2](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) for the correct filter

Comment: Thanks guys. versions - should be one, I was sure that jersey and jersey-server are different artifacts and have different dev cycles. Application - I used it, but I'm not really satisfied with this solution. I would rather let spring to configure it. I still don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have came accross here and frustrated with no solution, here is the solution I have ended up with:

For:

- Spring v3.2.9
- Jersey v1.18.1

**Filter Implementation**

```
package com.acme.sample.rest;
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("filtered");
        return request;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>IGT</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- jersey 1.x -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.acme.sample</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.acme.sample.rest.MyFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.sample" />
</beans>
```

**Provider class**
    package com.acme.sample;

```
@Component
@Path("/sample")
public class ApiProvider {

    // Add the bean's package to package scan of applicationContext.xml file
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/healthy")
    public Response getHealthy() {

        String output = "{\"status\":\"UP\"}";
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(output)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0
        rest-provider

```
    <name>jersey-servlet</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acme.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.18.1</jersey.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.9</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jersey-servlet</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```